# Why does my class-weighted model perform so strangely/bad?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Here are the accuracy and loss plots for the class-weighted version:
[image][image]

Here are the accuracy and loss plots for the unweighted version:
[image][image]

Here is the code. The only difference in the above two versions is that one calls the class weights dictionary and one doesn't. (General advice about how this is set up is also welcome -- as you can see I am very new to this!)

```py
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import optimizers
from keras.applications.resnet_v2 import ResNet50V2
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Rescaling, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten


#Create datasets
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/train/All classes/',
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",
    validation_split=0.2,
    seed=1337,
    subset="training",
)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/train/All classes/',
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",
    validation_split=0.2,
    seed=1337,
    subset="validation",
)

test_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/test/All classes/',
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",
)

#Import ResNet
base_model = ResNet50V2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

#Create basic network to append to ResNet above
x = base_model.output
x = Rescaling(1.0 / 255)(x)
x = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(256,256,3), padding="same")(x)
x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2)(x)
x = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2)(x)
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
predictions = Dense(units=5, activation='softmax')(x)

#Merge the models
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

#Freeze ResNet layers
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

#Compile
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-3), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

#These are the weights. They are derived here from their numbers in the train dataset -- there are 25,811 
#files in class 0, 2444 files in class 1, etc. This dictionary was not called for the unweighted version.
class_weight = {0: 1.0,
                1: 25811.0/2444.0,
                2: 25811.0/5293.0,
                3: 25811.0/874.0,
                4: 25811.0/709.0}

#Training the model
model_checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath='/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/ResNet/',
    save_weights_only=False,
    mode='auto',
    save_best_only=True,
    save_freq= 'epoch')

history = model.fit(
          x=train_ds,
          epochs=30,
          class_weight=class_weight,
          validation_data=val_ds,
          callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback]
)

#Evaluating
loss, acc = model.evaluate(test_ds)
print("Accuracy", acc)
```

Also, some other questions:

1. Should the `metrics=['accuracy']` actually be `metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy']`?
2. Should `class_weight=class_weight` actually be `sample_weight=sample_weight`? I couldn't tell the difference in the documentation, although most examples seem to use `class_weight`.
3. I only used padding in one Conv2D layer, and this was a bodge to force the whole thing to actually compile. Should I have been more consistent and used it for the other one too?
4. On that note, are there other ways my simple appended CNN model (it was called 'predictions') could be laid out to make better sense?
5. Ah yes, before I forget -- as you can see from the above code, I didn't preprocess the data in accordance with the [keras guidance for ResNet](https://keras.io/api/applications/resnet/#resnet50v2-function). I figured it probably wouldn't make that much of a difference (but also because I was having trouble trying to implement it). Would that be worth looking into? I suppose the unweighted model shows a very high accuracy... probably ***too*** high now that I'm looking at it... oh, dear.

I shall be so very thankful for any advice!

Comment: probably you have a very unbalanced dataset, and very uncorrelated feature or very few data

Comment: But isn't class_weights meant to account for unbalanced data? Also, the train dataset is made up of 35,151 images; the test dataset has even more (this is the Kaggle eyePACs dataset)..

Comment: yes, but that does not help getting higher accuracy with very unbalanced datasets

Comment: Wait so class_weights doesn't help correct for unbalanced data? What's it for then? And, what's the quickest way for me to fix this? Should I just remove most of the data until all classes have the same number of images? (I don't really want to do image augmentation)

Comment: It helps your model to have better generalization, not better accuracy... if you have 99% class 0, and 1% class 1, accuracy is 99% already if you just predict always 0... in other words, accuracy is not the right metric

Comment: I see. So class_weights help the model generalise over and above the train dataset it's seeing (well, the 80% of it that it can see, as 20% is reserved for validation). Should I now try to correct for class imbalance? Or should I use a metric other than simple Accuracy? Or both?

Comment: i don't know how unbalanced is your dataset and what you are trying to do, but in case it's as said before, you probably should read more about precision, recall, F1 and so on, and find a metric that actually reflects your interest